# Встраивание URL со скобками в личные сообщения

Tags: вконтакте, url

Например, необходимо в личном сообщении вставить ссылку на некий ресурс похожим образом:

```
https://example.com/page.html#element(01)
```

Но ссылка, вставленная просто как текст, будет вести на `https://example.com/page.html#element(01`,  где отсутствует последняя скобка, и прокрутка страницы к нужному элементу не сработает. 
Возможности попросить администратора ресурса переверстать страницу, например, указав ID элемента без скобок, отсутствует.

Как встроить такую ссылку?

Comment: А если так `https://example.com/page.html#element%2801%29`: https://example.com/page.html#element%2801%29 ?

Comment: @gil9red Да, спасибо. Что-то не подумал сам об этом. Вот только надо бы было добавить как ответ, а то коммент ответом не отметить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно запрос в `https://example.com/page.html#element(01)` конвертировать через [Percent-encoding / URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Получится такой адрес https://example.com/page.html#element%2801%29:

```
https://example.com/page.html#element%2801%29
```